# QGraphicsItem loses focus after using QComboBox

Tags: c++, qt

I am doing a small game in Qt and try to use WASD to move my protagonist(QGraphicsPixmapItem). The map is quite big so I use a QComboBox to change the scale of the scene.

The game looks like this:

The simple game

[image]

How I built the protagonist:

```
protagonist = new MyProtagonist();
protagonist->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsFocusable);
protagonist->setFocus();
scene->addItem(protagonist);
```

How I built the combox:

```
sceneScaleCombo = new QComboBox;
QStringList scales;
scales << tr("1%")<<tr("10%") << tr("20%") <<tr("50%") << tr("100%") <<tr("200%");
sceneScaleCombo->addItems(scales);
sceneScaleCombo->setCurrentIndex(4);
connect(sceneScaleCombo,SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(QString)),this,SLOT(sceneScaleChanged(QString)));

void MainWindow::sceneScaleChanged(const QString &scale)
{
    double newScale = scale.left(scale.indexOf(tr("%"))).toDouble() / 100;
    QMatrix oldMatrix = view->matrix();
    view->resetMatrix();
    view->translate(oldMatrix.dx(),oldMatrix.dy());
    view->scale(newScale,newScale);
    protagonist->setFocus();
}
```

Everything worked well at the beginning. However, after I clicking the combobox, my protagonist cannot be controlled by keyboard any more. I need to click my protagonist to make it focused again.

Is there any way to set it focused automatically?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you want us to help you, we need you to provide a [mcve]

Comment: instead of `protagonist->setFocus();` try `view->setFocus();`.

Comment: @scopchanov That works! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @scopchanov sorry, accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By clicking *QComboBox* the *QGraphicsView* looses the focus. You attempt to return it back by calling `setFocus();` on the *QGraphicsPixmapItem*. This approach doesn't work as you expect, because it sets the focus item inside the view, but the view itself still does not have focus. To fix that in `MainWindow::sceneScaleChanged` instead of `protagonist->setFocus();` write `view->setFocus();`.